# Disk doesn't contain valid partition table after switching /home to new drive

Tags: partitioning, mount

A couple days ago I moved my home directory to a new SSD I got. That was pretty painless and everything is working now, except one thing. Every time I boot up it says it found a problem on my disk (`/dev/sdc`) and allows me ignore, unmount, or manually fix it. I always choose ignore since everything's working for me. But last time I booted up I tried to fix it. I ran fdisk and that says:

> Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table.

How do I fix this?

If applicable, here's my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdc2 during installation
UUID=f766587d-5486-49fc-ba0c-48de358f38d7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdc3 during installation
UUID=973f8c23-0949-4c6c-8cd2-668cdf747859 none            swap    sw              0       0
# home folder
/dev/sdc    /media/neutron256gigssd     ext4    defaults    1   2
UUID=257a0481-1626-4f22-81ce-d5c853af1fb6   /home    ext4          nodev,nosuid       0       2
```

Edit: I've tried checking the drive in gparted, which didn't help. Also, the error I get on start up is "Serious errors were found while checking the disk for /home"

as requested, here is the output of

> mount; sudo parted /dev/sdc print free

```
/dev/sdb2 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/sdc on /media/neutron256gigssd type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sdc on /home type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup       (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=josh)
[sudo] password for josh: 
Model: ATA Corsair Neutron (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  256GB  256GB  ext4
```

Comment: Why is your `fstab` trying to mount the whole disk `/dev/sdc` to `/media/neutron256gigssd`? What's the output of `mount; sudo parted /dev/sdc print free`?

Comment: I'm trying to mount the entire disk since I couldn't find another way to mount it. I'll put the output of that in my question.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. It says your partition table is type `loop`. Also, why are you mounting the disk to that folder under `/media` AND to `/home`? I'll post an answer with some steps and let's see if it works, but first, what's the output of `sudo blkid /dev/sdc1`?

Comment: `sudo blkid /dev/sdc1' outputs nothing. And I'm not sure why I did that actually, haha. I think I initially mounted it to /media to copy my data to it and get the UUID and stuff and then to /home once that was complete and never bothered to change it. You think that's what's causing it?

Comment: Well yeah. Remove the line that's mounting it to `/media/neutron256gigssd` then restart and see if you don't get the error anymore. But otherwise your `/home` folder is working fine? Does the output of `df -h /home` say something like `/dev/sdc` and size 256G?

Comment: I did that and everything's good. :) Thanks. And the output of that does say that. Any way to mark this question as resolved?

Comment: I'll post an answer, you should be able to choose it as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `fstab` file shows that you're mounting the drive to two different mount points. Generally, I think that doesn't work. If you really wanted to do that, you could create a symbolic link to the original mount point.

But since you don't want to do that, and you don't need the disk to be mounted under the `/media` folder anymore, remove this line from your `fstab` file:

```
/dev/sdc    /media/neutron256gigssd     ext4    defaults    1   2
```

Restart or execute the command `mount -a` for the changes to take effect. This solved your problem (discussed under the comments section).